# In Azure, can I manipulate files on the webapp a webjob is deployed to?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a temporary "uploaded images" folder that resides on a webapp that periodically needs to culled of old images. I'd like the clean up task to be done via a continuous webjob. Is it possible to manipulate a folder on the webapp that the web job is deployed to via the webjob without essentially ftping to the webapp? ie. by the very nature of its deployment, can the webjob access the webapp and its files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. A WebJob can access all the Web App's files. Specifically, the WebJob can look under `%HOME%\site\wwwroot` to find the Web App's files. And presumably you have your upload folder somewhere under that.

You can use [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to get a sense of the file structure.